# Using js-routes gem with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am reading the documentation for it but still can't quite figure out how to set it up.

So far I created a `jsroutes.rb` file and gem in the `Gemfile` and declaring it in application.js file.

But now how to use it? What to do with jsroutes.rb file?  Can someone show me how to use this?

https://github.com/railsware/js-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS routes adds named routes to your javascript. you know how in view you can write new_blog_comment_path(@blog) and it automatically gives you `/blogs/:blog_id/comments/new` path? JS routes allows you to do same. So assuming you have blog and nested comments route, then you can use js-routes in your js: you can write Routes.new_blog_comment_path(blog_id_or_blog_json) and it will automatically generates string which is the path for that route.

Comment: Hey @luri G. I have a similar question. I did the steps that user1899082 did but am I supposed to do something with jsroutes.rb. The docs made it seem as if something would be generated. I'm confused because I'm not sure what needs to go into that file. Some help?

Comment: @DanRubio you dont need to add anything to jsroutes.rb unless you want to change some of the options that it has. Once you added it to your `application.js` and ran `rake tmp:cache:clear`, you can start your server and use Routes object in javascript. for example if you have a `posts` route in your routes.rb file, then in JS you can use `Routes.new_post_path()`, and it will return you string which will be path to posts (`/posts/new`)